# Search by tag in TiddlyWiki

Tags: search, tiddlywiki

I like the `search by tag` function on Super User.  I can search any post tagged with both [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and [macro](/questions/tagged/macro) using `[excel] [macro]`. Is there similar function for [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is either [MatchTagsPlugin](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#MatchTagsPlugin) by Eric Shulman (The TiddlyTools guy) or [YourSearchPlugin](http://tiddlywiki.abego-software.de/#YourSearchPlugin) by Udo Borkowski.

Both let you do full operator-enhanced tag searches but their syntax and other features differ.

[MatchTagsPlugin](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#MatchTagsPlugin) lets you set up a new search field which displays its results in a new tiddler in a configurable format and will search only tags using a syntax like this:

```
excel AND (macro OR script) AND NOT virus
```

If the provided interfaces don't do it for you, take a look at [what I did](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14610481/story_ideas.html#Welcome) using [InlineJavascriptPlugin](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#InlineJavascriptPlugin).

[YourSearchPlugin](http://tiddlywiki.abego-software.de/#YourSearchPlugin) modifies the existing search field to support a richer query syntax (and, optionally, a new results popup) and you can specify that a given entry should only match tags by prefixing it like this:

```
#excel (#macro or #script) not #virus
```

You could also poke around on [TiddlyHub](http://plugins.tiddlywiki.org/plugins/) to see if anything else might meet your needs.